# tableau group by and another column comparison to next row

Tags: tableau-desktop

I need to group by by a "name" column, sort values by "timestamp" column and then check if "activity" column value is the same as the value in the next row. Is it possible to do it in Tableau? Sounds like it would be pretty hard to do it and I have no clue how

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Please follow these steps:

1. drag "name" to the rows
2. drag "timestamp" to the rows right next to the "name", then click the arrow to sort the value
3. drag "activity" to the row right next to the "timestamp"

Hope it helps!

Comment: It does not look like it would check the value in the next row

Comment: @LaurynasG Maybe you can make a dataframe to show us what you mean about the next row?

Comment: There are 4 major types of calculations supported in Tableau. Table Calcs are the only type of calculation that can take row order into account. So read up on table calcs. There are two parts of a table calc definition - the formula itself, and information about how to group and sort the values that the table calc acts upon - known as partitioning and addressing aka compute using. The second part of the table calc definition takes a bit to learn but is at least as critical as the formula itself. Many times you can use a "quick" table calc to get the effect you want easily